# How to trigger DAG3 after successfully execution of DAG1 and DAG2 in airflow?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have created DAG1 and DAG2 which containing 2 task each inside it.
and in DAG3 by using triggerdagrunoperator triggering DAG1 and DAG2 and set parameter wait_for_completion and poke_interval of 15 sec.
But problem here is scheduler not working by this parameter...Scheduler got stop.
Here is my code for DAG3:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="controller_dag",
    default_args={"owner": "airflow"},
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    tags=['example'],
)
def BYE():
    return "GOOD BYE from Controller_Dag"

trigger1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dag_1",
    trigger_dag_id="target_dag_1",
    wait_for_completion = True,
    poke_interval = 15,
    dag=dag,
)
trigger2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dag_2",
    trigger_dag_id="target_dag_2",
    wait_for_completion =True,
    poke_interval = 15,
    dag=dag,
)

Bye = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "BYE",
    python_callable = BYE,
    dag=dag)

[trigger1, trigger2]>>Bye
```

If any knows why its happening please help me.
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Is the poking happening on the proper execution date? Could you please check the logs of TriggerDagRunOperator in DAG 3, against the execution time of DAGs 1 and 2 and confirm?

Comment: Without Wait_for_completion parameter its working fine..But with that parameter scheduler get stop. TriggerDagRunOperator in DAG3 giving error like.......airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2021-03-19 10:14:42,937] {taskinstance.py:1433} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=controller_dag, task_id=trigger_dag_1, execution_date=20210319T044355, start_date=20210319T044441, end_date=20210319T044442
[2021-03-19 10:14:42,948] {process_utils.py:61} INFO - Process psutil.
@JacobCelestine